# Which has optimal performance for generating a randomized list: `random.shuffle(ids)` or `.order_by("?")`?

Tags: python, mysql, django, optimization

I need to generate a randomized list of 50 items to send to the front-end for a landing page display. The landing page already loads much too slowly, so any optimization would be wonderful!

Given the pre-existing performance issues and the large size of this table, I'm wondering which implementation is better practice, or if the difference is negligible:

Option A:

```
unit_ids = list(units.values_list('id', flat=True).distinct())
random.shuffle(unit_ids)
unit_ids = unit_ids[:50]
```

Option B:

```
list(units.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by("?")[:50])
```

My concern is that according to the django docs, `order_by('?')` "may be expensive and slow"
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

We are using a MySQL db. I've tried searching for more info about implementation, but I'm not seeing anything more specific than what's in the docs. Help!

Comment: It depends.  First...  How many rows in table?  Are there `TEXT` columns?  How many will you display?  (Apparently "50")  Do you have a list of IDs in the client?  If not, what is the cost of getting such?

Answer (score 0):

Option B should be faster in most cases since a database engine is usually faster than a code in python.

In option A, you are retrieving some ids which should be all the ids by my guess and then you are shuffling them on python. and according to you, the table is large so that makes it a bad idea to do it in python. Also, you are only getting the ids which mean if you need the actual data, you have to make another query.

With all the explanations, you should still try both and see which one is faster because they both depend on different variables. Just time them both and see which one works faster for you and then go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Tradeoffs:

- Shoveling large amounts of data to the client (`TEXT` columns; all the rows; etc)
- Whether the table is so big that fetching N random rows is likely to hit the disk N times.

My first choice would be simply:

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50;
```

My second choice would be to use "lazy loading" (not unlike your `random.shuffle`, but better because it does not need a second round-trip):

```
SELECT t.*
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM t ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50 ) AS r
    JOIN t  USING(id)
```

If that is not "fast enough", then first find out whether the subquery is the slowdown or the outer query.

If the inner query is the problem, then see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

If the outer query is the problem, you are doomed.  It is already optimal (assuming `PRIMARY KEY(id)`).